# Extract MySql Connection ID right from the C# Connection Object

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I wonder whether there is a way to determine the Connection ID and LocalEndpoint's port used by MySql Connection on the C# side.

I know that I can run:

```
select * from information_schema.processlist
where id = connection_id();
```

However, my question is whether I can get these details (or at least the connection ID) without executing this SQL statement, that is, right from the Connection object itself (as this information DOES exist within the connection's underlying type and TCP socket)

Thanks :)

Comment: _"select connection_id();"_

Comment: @PaulF Yes, I know that and wrote it. I want a way to extract it from the connection object itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the [connection_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html) function says that it returns the thread ID of the current connection. If you check the documentation for [MySqlConnection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection.htm) you may find that the MySqlConnection equivalent of ClientConnectionId is [ServerThread](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/P_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection_ServerThread.htm) - I have done some testing & found that it contains the same value as returned by the query - but that may not be guaranteed.

I have not found a way of determining the TCP port from publicly accessible properties/methods.

Comment: Note one major exception to this: if you connect through a MySQL Proxy, the `ServerThread` property will be initialized to a value returned by the proxy during the initial handshake. This may be different from the `connection_id()` of the backend server you ultimately connect to. (This happens, for example, with Azure Database for MySQL: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b7afa58f-5a96-432a-86e8-e6ea5fefb258/threadid-mismatch-in-azure-instance-for-mysql?forum=AzureDatabaseforMySQL.) MySqlConnector detects and works around this situation: https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector

Answer (score 0):

The connection string is parsed into Properties of the Connection class. It might have ceased existing once it was processed. Look at the Propeties you have availible: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.aspx#Properties

As for getting Connection details - that is problematic. Internally the SQLConnection class is doing Connection Pooling. So the same low-level connection might be re-used for a request that comes soon after. Like Thread ID's, it is the kind of thing you should not really access in your code.

These values could change even during execution without any obvious forwarning, rhyme or reason (there is still a reason, but it is hard to even get a decent guess). The Behavior Might change between Framework Versions, Specific Circumstances in that Millisecond, or even if your Grandmother visits or wheter you have a full moon or not today.

Comment: As OP is using MySQL, so possibly using MySqlConnection - this link is appropriate : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection.htm - that class does have a ServerThread property which equates to the connection ID.

Comment: @PaulF: Server Threads are less likely to be consistent. If you got a Thread Pool, as Tasks are paused/delayed/have to wait, they may be dropped by one thread and picked up by another later. I fully expect SQL Servers to have those basic level Optimisations. If you really need to know the TCP Connection, you propably will not get around creating it - and all the surrounding code DBConnections do for you - yourself.

Comment: _"[CONNECTION_ID()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/6.10/html/T_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlConnection.htm) Returns the connection ID (thread ID) for the connection. Every connection has an ID that is unique among the set of currently connected clients."_ - checking the _"select connected()"_ query & matching to the ServerThread property has shown consistently to be the same - but I agree that this cannot be guaranteed.

Comment: @Christopher, I was asking about MySql connection not SQL Server. 
MySqlConnection object does not contain ClientCollectionId property or  equivalent.

Comment: If you check the documentation you may find that the MySqlConnection equivalent of ClientConnectionId is ServerThread - I have done some testing & found that it contains the same value as returned by the query. I have not found a way of determining the TCP port from publicly accessible properties/methods.

Comment: @PaulF you're right, although it might not be the same in some cases.
Make an answer so I can mark it as an answer. 
However, it is possible that this will not be the client ID (note that the client ID is defined as BIGINT(21)).
I probably have to use ServerThread or some sort of reflection to drill down into the connection object to extract the accurate ID.